# sqlite unrecognized token

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

i am using sqlite for wp7,it throws an exception when i try to insert a record that includes chinese charset,such as the statement below,the chinese string is made at random.

```
insert into tds_task(
        t_name,t_creator,t_sender,t_contents,t_importance,t_state,t_tag,
        t_assignto,t_createtime,t_starttime,t_donetime,t_deadlinetime,
        t_secrets,t_remindtime,t_category,t_attachments,t_rowguid)
        values('科斯特纳目录服务员工们kpkek0哭哭啼','example@example.com','',**'科斯特纳目录服务员工们kpkek0哭哭啼啼兔兔玉兔不图啊啊兔福田汽车业界碑林博物馆学院奖励工资条10拖拖拉拉她她她退下局势必，就算方法'**,'0','0','','','2012-08-05 15:36:50','0001-01-01 00:00:00','0001-01-01 00:00:00','2012-08-05 16:06:00','0','0001-01-01 00:00:00','default','','7200273c-94a6-4e0f-83c0-c4b345cfa01e');
```

it throwed this exception:

```
unrecognized token: "'科斯特纳目录服务员工们kpkek0哭哭啼啼兔兔玉兔不图啊啊兔福田汽车业界碑林博物馆学院奖励工资条10拖拖拉拉她她她退"
```

Comment: Also buggy using sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/60559/1 For me only 1 character causes the bug: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/60559/19

Comment: Hex editor sees this (using MacRoman encoding) `insert into tds_task( t_name)
values('ÈÄÄ');`

Comment: it can not expect what character would lead to this problem for me,everything is ok,except that i input chinese,last time ,the character that results in exception is "一",a chinese word, which means "a",the same as 1.did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, but I upvoted your question, because it is quite a scary situation.

Comment: It might be an SQLite bug: 3.6.12 OK: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d41d8/17  3.7.10 NOT OK: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d41d8/165

Comment: No,no,no,my entire project is down just because this tiny bug.

Comment: Maybe ask the SQLite mailing list: http://www.sqlite.org/src/wiki?name=Bug+Reports

Comment: @biziclop So you know, the version reported by http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d41d8/17 will depend on whatever browser you're using. For me, in Chrome 20.0.1132.57, it reports 3.7.6.3.

Comment: @JakeFeasel: Yeah, I know :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x91oF8b6k6w

Comment: @biziclop lol, okay cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u there? I got the problem.I found if the text string include Full-width characteristic
then u can't insert that into the sqlite datebase.if u are a chinese programer, I could provide u more information about how to solve this question. A simple way to clear that is convert Full-width string into half-width string. u can google the code to do that!

Comment: hi, that is great, i don't understand what the Full-width and Half-widh string are,i searched,but didn't find a appropriate answer, can you show me how to do it in wp7 with c#?thanks

Comment: I'm strongly recommend u using sqlce,that database was included in sdk7.1, sqlite db is too shit in wp platform

Comment: i do agree with you, don't use SQLite in wp7 guys,it is a shit.